# No reverse match when rendering an email template with uid/token variable

Tags: django, django-urls

I wrote a view for user signup including email verification. However, once the view tries to render the mail template, it breaks due to the below error.

I don't even understand the error itself. Insights would be appreciated. According to some googling it may be that the `uid` is no string?

> NoReverseMatch at /signup/
> Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': 'MTE', 'token': 'asnwwr-550108ae10aa04da212561866c8d1ae3'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activate/(?P[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']

Mail template

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},

Please click on the link below to confirm your registration:

http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

View

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate your Poller Account'
            message = render_to_string('userprofile/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),   # Issue might sit here?
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('account_activation_sent')
```

Token

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
import six


class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.email_confirmed)
        )

account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

Url

```
url(r'^account_activation_sent/$', signup_views.account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', signup_views.activate, name='activate'),
```

Comment: you pass uidb64 and token as a **kwargs** in template file but your url accept **args** . Share urls.py file code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be raised because your token has 32 characters, but the regex only expects up to 20. Try to change the regex to:

```
r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,32})/$'
                                                                   # Change to 32 ^^
```

Comment: that worked, thanks. Quick question: Would it hurt if I would increase to lets say 50 or some to avoid this conflict again or is the above token generation logic that way that it always will provide a token with 32 chars?

Comment: It depends on the token you are generating. Can it have arbitrary length?

Comment: tbh idk, will have to check out the PasswordResetTokenGen docu then. Thanks again!